# The issue is with import 'package:stop_watch_timer/stop_watch_timer.dart';

Tags: flutter, dart, import

lib/screens/Questions/Question.dart:171:25: Error: The getter 'onExecute' isn't defined for the class 'StopWatchTimer'.

- 'StopWatchTimer' is from 'package:stop_watch_timer/stop_watch_timer.dart' ('/C:/Users/shama/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/stop_watch_timer-3.1.0+4/lib/stop_watch_timer.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'onExecute'.
  time.stopWatchTimer.onExecute.add(StopWatchExecute.start);
  ^^^^^^^^^
  Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.

> Process 'command 'C:\Users\shama\Downloads\flutter_windows\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 45s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           46.8s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

I think the problem is with the package!!

```
`import 'package:stop_watch_timer/stop_watch_timer.dart';`
```

someone help with an alternative in the code snippet
`@override void initState() { super.initState(); getCurrentQuestion(); //time.stopWatchTimer.start(); time.stopWatchTimer.onExecute.add(StopWatchExecute.start); }`

Comment: Add your code. You are calling onExecute on the StopWatchTimer class somewhere but that method isn’t defined for StopWatchTimer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.